# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Session::set_cookie()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Session::set_cookie()
```

I have included cookie library in my controller:

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

Now, I am setting cookie like this:

```
 $this->session->set_cookie('pname',$this->input->post('type'));
```

But I'm getting a fatal error.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Set_cookie is from helper. You do not need yo use $this->session, it is just a function :

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
set_cookie('pname',$this->input->post('type'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cookie Helper provides friendlier syntax, but an alternative is to not load it and just use the [Input Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html), which is auto-loaded.

You can do this by passing an array:

```
$cookie = array(
    // Required parameters
    'name'   => 'pname',
    'value'  => $this->input->post('type'),
    // Optional parameters
    //'expire' => '86500',
    //'domain' => '.some-domain.com',
    //'path'   => '/',
    //'prefix' => 'myprefix_',
    //'secure' => TRUE
);

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

Or using discrete parameters:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('pname', $this->input->post('type'));
```